# How do I prove A(B+C) = AB + AC in Boolean algebra?

Tags: logic, logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcJin.jpg)

Hi everyone, I need help to prove that A(B+C) = AB + AC in Boolean. It’s been years since I did this and a friend asked for help. I tried but I can’t seem to get it right. Can someone explain how to prove it using Boolean? And where did I go wrong in the picture?

Comment: Maybe you're just wanting to do a 1/0 truth table for the left and right hand sides for each value of A, B, and C and show that the results are the same? You could write a program to do that. If it's not a programming question, though, then the question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I think it really comes down to basic algebra. In regular (non-boolean) math `ab + ac = a(b + c)` and here is an example `2*3 + 2*4 = 2*(3+4)`. If you calculate it `6 + 8 = 2*7`. This is called [distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property). I don't really know how you formally prove the distributive law - it must be possible but I just take it as granted that it exists. So, it might be worth looking for a proof of the law.

Answer (score -1):

As I know the proofs are made by De Morgan's laws.

Comment: I don't see how `¬(A + B) = ¬A . ¬B` and `¬(A.B) = ¬A + ¬B` applies here.